# Is there any way to find info about C keywords from linux command line?

Tags: c, linux, manual

Does linux provide any tools to provide the information like man which will give me the details about the c keywords?
For. e.g. man auto

Comment: Nope. You can use: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword or other similar resources. Any textbook will give you the same info.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation P.P.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek answer: `wget`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/topics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it directly. As P.P. pointed out in the comments you can check out the doc on the  [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) website.

However you can install [`cpp man`](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman) on your machine, which will allow you to  consult these reference pages as a man page offline on your computer.
It is quite convenient especially if you have to work without a network connexion for a while (e.g. in the plane or train).